Counters and logging associated with LISTEN/NOTIFY
We're seeing an issue where NOTIFY events are sometimes not received by the application that is listening on the channel. We are using Go's pgx's WaitForNotification() API to receive notifications; a dump of the stack trace indicated the goroutine was waiting at the WaitForNotification() call. We are sending the events on a trigger using PERFORM pg_notify() during inserts and deletes. The application did not receive events after restarting it. We saw the same behavior using the NOTIFY command from psql. After we restarted the database, the application started to receive notifications.
Are there any logging/counters associated with the LISTEN/NOTIFY mechanism that would help us debug this problem when it does happen again?
We are using Postgres 16.

You can make the trigger save some logging info into a table of your own design, or the client can save its pg_notification_queue_usage () output somewhere. This tends to happen if you stretch your transactions too long and the notify queue runs out of space. Related

Does pg_notification_queue_usage() return a global value, meaning that when this problem happens, I can login through psql and see the usage? The goroutine that processes the notifications is doing nothing but waiting for notifications during this time.

Notifications are only sent when the sending transaction commits. Please check if you forgot to commit the transaction.

@user2233706 Correct. You can open 3 psql sessions on a clean db: in the first one, issue listen c1; begin;, from another one, send some select pg_notify('c1',repeat(gen_random_uuid()::text,220)); and in the third one you can watch select pg_notification_queue_usage(); go up. Once you commit or rollback in the first, listening session, you'll see all those notifications come in and the function pg_notification_queue_usage will return to zero.

Adding to Laurenz Albe above, notifications aren't sent or received mid-transaction - in both cases they'll queue up. If the sender is mid-transaction, they aren't even emitted, so they won't be reflected by pg_notification_queue_usage(). Once they do get sent, they wait there for all current listeners to complete their work. To track the emitter side that keeps their transaction uncommitted, you might want to raise notice (log/info/debug) from that trigger and watch the log - after all, unless they commit, if you instead save to a table, it will also wait for the commit.

@LaurenzAlbe The inserts/deletes are not not wrapped in a transaction. I can see the updated rows in psql, therefore the transaction was committed, but I did not get an event notification.

Not even when you sent a statement to the server?

I haven't tried inserting a row from psql to see if the notification is received (if that's what you mean). I did not get a notification when I used NOTIFY from psql.
